# Why doesn't Code Contracts static analyzer treat these property getter calls as equal?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I'm trying to set up an immutable ordered singly-linked list class using code contracts to enforce the ordering.  I'm running into some problems that boil down to this example:

```
[Pure, ContractVerification(true)]
public class Hierarchy
{
    private readonly object _data;
    private readonly Hierarchy _childField;

    public Hierarchy() { }

    public Hierarchy(object data, Hierarchy childParameter) {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(childParameter != null);

        _data = data;
        _childField = childParameter;

        Contract.Assert(HasChild);

        Contract.Assert(_childField == childParameter);
        Contract.Assert(_childField.Data == childParameter.Data);

        Contract.Assert(ChildProperty == _childField);
        Contract.Assert(ChildProperty.Data == _childField.Data);  //Warning -- CodeContracts: assert unproven
    }

    public bool HasChild { get { return _childField != null; } }

    public object Data {
        get {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<object>() == _data);
            return _data;
        }
    }

    public Hierarchy ChildProperty {
        get {
            Contract.Requires<InvalidOperationException>(HasChild);
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Hierarchy>() == _childField);

            //un-commenting this line causes the assertion to succeed.
            //Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Hierarchy>().Data == _childField.Data);

            return _childField;
        }
    }

    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    private void Invariant() {
        Contract.Invariant(HasChild == (ChildProperty != null));
    }
}
```

It seems to me that code contracts ought to be able to prove the assertion `ChildProperty.Data == _childField.Data`.  The earlier assertion `ChildProperty == _childField` succeeds, and calling the pure `Data` property getter twice on the same object should return the same result.

Note also the (successful) earlier assertions that `_childField == childParameter` and `_childField.Data == childParameter.Data`.

As noted in the second comment above, the problem is resolved by adding the postcondition `Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Hierarchy>().Data == _child.Data);` to the `ChildProperty` getter.  Note that this is all we need to do -- in this case, code contracts recognizes that when `x == y`, calling the `Data` getter on x and y will yield the same result.

This workaround is fine for this small example, but for a large class, it's burdensome (not to mention somewhat silly) to have to add a postcondition for each of the type's properties.

Is it a bug?  Have I missed some contract annotation or something else that would allow the assertion `Child.Data == _child.Data` to be proven?  In other words, is there some other way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are absolutely right. This should be provable, but is not due to limitations in the static checker.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because the `Data` property makes no guarantee not to change the contents of `_data` (although it's `readonly`, its contents are still potentially mutable)?

For example, suppose you had this:

```
public object Data {
    get {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<object>() == _data);
        ((SomeClass)_data).SomeProperty += 1;
        return _data;
    }
}
```

Then two subsequent calls to `Data` would get different results.

Does adding this to `Data`'s `get` work?

```
Contract.Ensures(_data == Contract.OldValue<object>(_data));
```

Comment: Well -- if that were true, why would other calls to `Contract.Assert(x.Data == y.Data)` succeed?  Also, mutating an object doesn't change the value of the reference, so even if _data were mutated, the reference equality check should succeed.  Still, I added the postcondition you suggested, to the ChildProperty getter, and it did not change the result.

Comment: +1 though, for reminding me of Contract.OldValue, which I had overlooked for some reason; that helped me solve another problem.

Comment: It's an interesting problem. I realise this answer doesn't solve it, but I'll leave it up in case it helps someone else figure out what's going on.